# How to make a search fucntion to search a dataframe displayed in pandas that the user can use

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, search

I need help learning to make a search function that a user can use. I am a first-year student and this is my first programming class. I need help on how to make a search function that a user can use to search a displayed CSV file for a specific column. I don't know a lot about programming. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a kind of a very basic python-pandas question, one that you should be able to do by yourself once you get acquainted with it and practice.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @cmosig Such as when I display the DataFrame one column is "pts" how can I make a search function that the user can use to input keywords to pull that columns. Search:"pts" and the program displays only the "pts" column.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan I have tried searching but most use Jupyter notebook and I am not allowed to use that.

Comment: if `col` is the column in dataframe `df` and `val` is the search_term, you should be able to get the filtered df, by - `df.loc[df['col'] == 'val']` or even better, `df.loc[df['col'].str.contains('val')]`